# Setting up an SSRS data source to show only some views from the database

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am currently looking at setting up a number of SSRS data sources to a warehouse but one issue I can not get around is how to define which views are available to each data source. Can someone share how to limit these down so that I can have multiple data sources acting as data marts from the single warehouse.

Currently using SQL 2008 r2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a view you assign a permission set to the view (certain users/groups can do selects others can do selects and inserts and others have no permission on the view).

When you set up a connection through a datasource the user on the datasource will have the permissions assigned to them through the view. When you deploy the report you assign a user and password to the report (Data Source) and that user's permission will apply to what they can objects that, and the report, can see. The permissions assigned to the report allow users to see/execute the report.

Comment: Thanks for the response - As I am simply hacking about to get better views I am a bit loath to mess about with to much as this is to be transferred across to the production model later. I will work with them spilt up into separate databases referencing the source database for now as I can get that working without to much setting up.